# Unity why is WheelCollider toque so slow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I followed so many tutorials but can't find why my car is so slow?

Values:

[image: values]

`max toque = 1000` also tried like `8000` doesn't work

steer angle 45 can't almost steer

```
mass 1500
```

Wheel colliders:

[image: wheel collider values]

Code:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     float motor = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     float steering = steerAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

     foreach (Axis axle in axles)
     {
         if (axle.steer)
         {
             axle.wheelLeft.steerAngle = steering;
             axle.wheelRight.steerAngle = steering;
         }
         if (axle.useMotor)
         {
             axle.wheelLeft.motorTorque = motor;
             axle.wheelRight.motorTorque = motor;
         }

         ApplyWheelVisualRotation(axle.wheelRight);
         ApplyWheelVisualRotation(axle.wheelLeft);
     }
 }
```

Comment: If Programmer gave you the solution for your problem you should accept his answer, so the question is marked as solved. In case you still need further help you should comment his answer explaning what is still not working or what is missing from your point of view

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the first screenshot you posted, *"Wheel FL"* and *"Wheel FR"* have their *Use Motor* variable disabled.

This must be enabled or only *"Wheel RL"* and  *"Wheel RR"* wheels will be moved by the physics engine. Both of these wheels will then have to drag *"Wheel FL"* and *"Wheel FR"* with them which slows the car down.

Also, the reduce the stiffness of the `WheelCollider`. The one you can find in your second screenshot under *Forward* and *Sideways Friction*. Start with *0.1* value and go up from there.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but it didn't work tried to lower the friction to 0.1 on all wheels and tried higher. also enabling motor on front and rear didn;t help the car keeps being slow.

Comment: Also, increase the "max toque" to about 5,000. It's currently at 1000. If still slow are you sure that the collider is not colliding with anything?

Comment: Can you upload the project somewhere and provide the link here? It can be a simplified version of the project. I will take a look at it. It will also be helpful if you can record the speed you are getting and post that too so that I can compare that with the speed on my side.